# When reading File : String index out of range: -1

Tags: java

I am new to java development,could you please help me out to find the solution for the below error.My Requirement is : if i give my DirectoryName, it has to read all the files from Directory and it has to print each file extension,filename,pathname.Note: DirectoryName contains subdirectory and inside the subdirectory one more directory and  then it contains the file  .
so when i was runing the code i am getting the error as :
D:\Testfolder\FileUtilities.java

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: -1

```
public class FolderSearch {
public void listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(String DirectoryName)
{
    File file = new File(DirectoryName);
    File[] filelist = file.listFiles();
    for(File pathname:filelist)
    {
    if(pathname.isFile())
        {
            String FPATH = pathname.getAbsolutePath();
            System.out.println(FPATH);
            Filename myfilename = new Filename(FPATH, '/', '.');

            System.out.println("Path =" + myfilename.fpath());
            System.out.println("FileName =" + myfilename.fname());
            System.out.println("Ext =" + myfilename.extension());   
        }
        else if(pathname.isDirectory())
        {
            listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(pathname.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    } ``
}
public static void main (String [] args)
{
    FolderSearch fs = new FolderSearch();
    final String DirectoryName = "D:/Testfolder";
    fs.listFilesAndFilesSubDirectories(DirectoryName);
}
}

public class Filename {
protected String filepath;
protected char pathseparator;
protected char extension;
Filename(String str,char ps,char e)
{
    filepath = str;
    pathseparator = ps;
    extension = e;
}
public String extension()
{
    int dot = filepath.lastIndexOf(extension);
    return filepath.substring(dot + 1);
}
public String fname()
{
    int dot = filepath.lastIndexOf(extension);
    int sep = filepath.lastIndexOf(pathseparator);
    return filepath.substring(sep + 1, dot);
}
public String fpath()
{
    int sep = filepath.lastIndexOf(pathseparator);
    return filepath.substring(0, sep);
}
}
```

Comment: Show the complete stack trace, and identify the line in your code that throws the exception.

Comment: Read the exception! READ THE EXCEPTION!! They aren't just random garbage put there to annoy you. They tell you useful stuff!

Comment: "minus one" is what `indexOf` calls return when the search string was not found.  (*) Stack overflow does not let me type the number "minus one" in a comment....

Comment: You never check return value of [`lastIndexOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29): *"Returns the index of the last occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, **or -1 if the character does not occur**."*

Comment: if you see my DirectoryName, i am passing D:/Testfolder where i have used if condition to find whether it is File or Forlder. So after the first if condition it gets the file path and then pass it to FPATH variable to store the path and i am sending that path into the FILENAME constructor.
So, there is no chance not to find the lastIndexof and i am getting that error at this particular line System.out.println("Path =" + myfilename.fpath());

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got,why it is returning -1.Because the output File is having an backslash separator '\',but i am passing '/' as character.
so i got the output by passing '\' double backslash as my argument to path separator in the class FileName.
this the file i am passing :

```
C:\Users\sl00338409\Desktop\WorkSpace\javainterface\javainterface\projects\taskinterface\datasource\ClarityTaskDataSource.java
```

So i need to pass backslash as character in the constructor, instead i am passing forward slash '/'.I got output by passing '\\' as character argument in the constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In you code, you have to check to make sure that `lastIndexOf` is not returning `-1`

For example

```
public String extension()
{
    int dot = filepath.lastIndexOf(extension);
    // if extension is not found then -1 is returned
    if (dot == -1) {
        return null;  // maybe throw a an exception
    }
    return filepath.substring(dot + 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi Scary,
i am getting error at System.out.println("Path =" + myfilename.fpath()); .

Comment: what error?  Maybe there is no path?